# SQL Query Syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Can anyone help me understand this line in `SQL`.

```
COALESCE
(

    COUNT
    (
        DISTINCT (
                CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(o.order_date,o.first_order_date) <= 30 AND DATEDIFF(o.order_date,o.first_order_date) > 0 AND DATE_FORMAT(o.first_order_date,'%Y-%m') < DATE_FORMAT(now()- INTERVAL 1 MONTH,'%Y-%m') AND o.status_id in (11,22,24)
                    THEN o.customer_id
                END
            )
    ),
    0   
) as '0-30 customer reorder'.
```

Comment: The line is incomplete

Comment: plz ask ur question clearly...

Comment: ask about specific things you do not understand. if you do not understand anything, you should first follow some SQL tutorial(s).

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? (You're using product specific functionality here, so you can't be using both...)

Comment: Pretty-format the expression using a single statement or function call on line, balance the parentheses, use the online documentation of the SQL flavor you are using and you will be able to decipher it yourself in no time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, look at `COALESCE(a,b)` means if a is not null then return a else return b.

The second part is `COUNT DISTINCT` which will count all values that are different (distinct).

And then a `CASE WHEN` that will output something different according to some conditions.

So here the case when says when the order_date of o is less than 30 after you first_order_date (`datediff(o.order_date,o.first_order_date) <= 30`), and the order_date and the first_order_date are different [strictly speaking it's "if the order_date is after first_order_date, but I assume first_order_date is necessarily before order_date) (`datediff(o.order_date,o.first_order_date) > 0`) and that your first_order_date is (strictly) older than one month (`date_format(o.first_order_date,'%Y-%m') <date_format(now()- interval 1 month,'%Y-%m')`) and the status_id is in (11,22,24) (`o.status_id in (11,22,24)`) then you put the value o.customer_id (`THEN o.customer_id END`, I guess otherwise it will be null).

Okay, so now you make a COUNT DISTINCT on that so you count all different ids so basically you count all order_id that verify all conditions above.

Finally, you make a COALESCE on the COUNT so if there were no rows that corresponded to your condition, it would return 0. Edit : Here I mean if there were no rows corresponding to your case when then you would do your COUNT DISTINCT on nothing (NULL), so to avoid problems he put a COALESCE to return 0 if no rows correspond to you CASE WHEN conditions.

Not sure I was clear.